# gdal_merge.py with single band raster

Tags: raster, gdal, imagery, mosaic, gdal-merge

I'm trying to mosaic the [True Marble world imagery](http://www.unearthedoutdoors.net/global_data/true_marble/download) 250M geotiffs using [gdal_merge.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) though one of them doesn't have RGB bands like the rest and gdal_merge fails (same number of bands is listed as a requirement in it's documentation). This is the error I get:

```
python.exe : ERROR 5: TrueMarble.250m.21600x21600.B4.tif: GDALDataset::GetRasterBand(2) - Illegal band #
```

This is the tile causing the issue: `TrueMarble.250m. 21600x21600.B4`

Should I use a different mosaic tool or should I try to coerce the tile into the format gdal_merge requires somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran across this mosaicing the True Marble imagery as well, though I used gdalbuildvrt and then gdal_translate. From memory, the recalcitrant tiffs are stored as a single band with a color table.

Just convert them to 3 band RGB with [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html):

```
gdal_translate -expand rgb TrueMarble.250m.21600x21600.B4.tif TrueMarble.250m.21600x21600.B4.RGB.tif
```

Comment: That's it! thanks Luke :) I tried just gdal_translate in hopes that might do it but I wasn't aware of the `-expand` parameter :). btw +1 for use of the word recalcitrant :P